# Como colocar 2 PWA instalaveis no mesmo site?

Tags: pwa

Possuo um site 
Ex: https://www.meusite.com/
Esse site possue um admin
Ex: https://www.meusite.com/admin

Quero colocar 1 app instalavel para cada um dos 2 endereços.
Coloquei 2 manifest.json com shortname e name diferentes, fiz até um serviceworker pra cada um, não resolveu..

Comment: cada manifest deve ter um escopo e start_url diferentes configurados

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.
Mas os dois estao com essas chaves iguais

"Scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",

Comment: Desculpe caro Gabriel, não dá para entender, como assim iguais? Tem que ser diferentes os escopos e os start_urls de cada manifest. Aliais seria melhor isolar cada "webapp" por pasta e o site principal não ser um webapp, no máximo usar serviceWorker para manter a index offine para acessar os webapps

Comment: Outra coisa, olhando suas perguntas sobre pwa me causa a sensação que vc esta usando o conceito PWA de forma desnecessária.

Comment: Dentro do arquivo manifest.json, ele tem chaves.. ambos os arquivos estão com as mesmas chaves.. Voce tinha colocado que precisa colocar scope e start_url diferentes...

Comment: O conceito de PWA esta correto, mas essa duvida não estava postada.. 
COm certeza mais pessoas utilizam apps diferentes como no meu caso..

Mas obrigado pelo seu tempo..

Comment: Não é isso, eu entendo o que vc quer atingir, mas PWA é mais do que algo que funciona, é uma série de conceitos, o que estou querendo é te guiar no caminho ideal, você pode transformar uma moto em um carro se vc for um mecanico razaovel e fazer funcionar, mas no fundo não é carro... entende? A intenção de transformar a INDEX/HOME do seu site em um PWA me parece estranha, tem uma coisa vc querer e outra coisa é se realmente isso é necessário. Outra coisa, fazer o PWA funcionar não significa o conceito estar correto, uma coisa é "a mecanica" disto, a outra coisa é o "conceito".

Comment: Outra coisa, não estava falando do scopo comparado com com start_url, eu estava falando do scope e start_url do primeiro manifest comparado com o do segundo manifest, mas tudo bem, espero que com o tempo eu consiga lhe abrir a mente, é que realmente eu não vi os códigos e a afins e por isso não tenho como saber o que fez para fazer apontamentos técnicos. Boa sorte então.

Comment: Não quero me especializar no PWA, só faze-lo funcionar inicialmente. É o bastante.
Em relação  a 2a resposta, foi o que respondi.. o scope e o start_url estavam iguais.

Comment: Caro Gabriel, vc ainda não entendeu, eu já disse que não é sobre o scope comparado ao start_url, não é se ambos são iguais, é sobre os 2 manifests ... outra coisa, não é sobre ser especialista, é sobre usar quando necessário e de forma ideal, fazer funcionar por fazer funcionar é praticamente aleatório, eu só quero te guiar no básico mesmo, pois notei esta "aparente" confusão ao olhar todas suas perguntas, mas em outra oportunidade talvez eu consiga elucidar sua ideia sobre tudo isto. Um abraço.

Comment: Eu acho que a gente não ta conseguindo se comunicar direito, porém se voce tiver alguma referencia pode passar ai pra eu aprimorar meus conhecimentos. Obrigado

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido.

Quando se precisa ter 2 apps instlaveis no mesmo site, o arquivo manifest.json precisa ter 2 nomes tambem.

admin-manifest.json  e manifest.json

Se tiver os dois manifest.json, mesmo em lugares diferentes, ele nao vai permitir instalar 2 apps